# How to iterate over one column to get the mean for each row?

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, categorical-data

I have a pyspark dataset in which there's one column named as numerical data.
I calculated this dataset from somewhere else.
Example:

```
 Numerical_fields| Age | Height | Weight
```

Now, I need to calculate mean for each value in this column.
For this I tried Looping, for i in `df.collect()`:
how can I get the mean?

Comment: Please show us your code

Comment: data_collect = df2.collect()
    for f in df2.collect(): 
        print (f.mean)

Comment: Please edit your question and put the code there, correctly formatted, and more of your code than just that one line please

Comment: Please see [How to make good reproducible Apache Spark examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48427185/how-to-make-good-reproducible-apache-spark-examples) and update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

To get a df with the mean of each value in Numerical_fields you can do the following:

```
avg_df = df.groupby(df.Numerical_fields).avg("Age", "Height", "Weight")
```

avg_df will now contain one line per unique value in `Numerical_fields` with the averages of the other columns for that value.